# Python pip reference to global path after venv is activated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I've a fresh installed MX-Linux. My PC contains 1 SSD with the OS installed and 1 HDD where I've always had my projects along with other general stuff (Photos etc..). Now the issue I'm having is that when I create a new virtual environment in any project inside my hard drive, it comes with all the global dependencies installed already and no matter if it has the dependencies a said project of mine requires, it'll fail to run. In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZFKa.jpg) at the top you will find how my venv looks like when I create it in my SSD (Which is how it is expected and works properly) and at the bottom how it looks when I create in inside my HHD. You see, the problem is that even after venv is activated, the pip path points to the global instead of the venv's

I've ran windows, fedora, mint and now MX. Never had this issue before and I can't find anything related online, thanks..

```
(venv) mx-linux@mx:/media/seconddrive/python-project/typer

$ which python
/media/seconddrive/python-projects/typer/venv/bin/python

$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```